# List files and folders from localhost in windows 8 app using javascript

Tags: windows-8

How to list files ad folders in localhost using JavaScript in windows 8 app instead of using file picker ?

Answer (score 1):

By "localhost" I presume you mean what's in the local storage for the application?  i.e., ms-appdata:///local?

If so you can grab a reference to the top level storage for the [local folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder.aspx). Then use methods of [StorageFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder.aspx) (like [GetFilesAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227276.aspx) and [GetFoldersAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227280.aspx)) to navigate the hierarchy.  There are some overloads that use [CommonFolderQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.search.commonfolderquery.aspx) for some additional functionality.

If you're trying to get access to other aspects of the file system on that machine, you will need to ask permission from the user (via file/folder picker) but once that permission has been granted it includes all subfolders, and you can retain the fact you got that permission via [AccessCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br207498.aspx) and not ask on subsequent runs.